# Backbone route is firing twice

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-routing

I'm using Backbone with Marionette and I have one troublesome route that seems to be firing twice, with different route parameters.  When you click back, it brings you back to the first firing of the route, not the original page.  Using Backbone Debugger, I can see that I have 6 different routers and only one of them (highlighted) has the applicable route.  So there's only one instance.

[image]

The route is being triggered by a plain old  link.  I'm not using navigate().  Here is the actual link HTML:

```
<a href="#device/3/hash/84855d0624dbeb7957cad7d09f7faca78166f033ab71e53aa6199f285d6d903f/incident/8IFVA" class="btn btn-actions action-details">
    <span></span> &nbsp;App
</a>
```

When I click on that link, you can see the route being triggered with two different signatures:

[image]

[image]

I feel like I may be misunderstanding how Backbone routes work, why my route definition is matching with and without the incidentId.  Here's the funny thing.  If I take that link and just paste it into the browser, the route is only triggered once.

Answer (score 2):

Generally when routes or events fire multiple times, it usually means that a view is not being properly disposed as you navigate back and forth.

Since you are sure that you aren't doing any hand-written navigation, it seems that this would be the case, especially if you only see this trigger once when you access the URL manually.

Without seeing your router or view code, it is hard to really give you a reliable solution. I would start putting breakpoints on that specific route handler and check the call stack of where it is being triggered.